# Filtering in ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList mixed = new ArrayList { "Joe", 200, "Root", false, "David" };
```

What is business logic should I use to filter only string from given `ArrayList`?

I mean I need `{"Joe","Root","David"}` as a filtered result.

I am using C# 4.0

Comment: Why in the name of all that is good, do you use `ArrayList` at all? Why oh why do you have a list made of different types?

Comment: Gotta agree with Oded. Your list is from Hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
 var StringOnly = mixed.OfType<string>();
```

to filter your arraylist.